# node.js deployment: how to get notified by email when "npm install" fails

Tags: node.js, deployment, npm

After each deployment through a GitHub webhook, I often end up ssh'ing into my server checking why my app isn't running. Most of the time it's because `npm install` failed due to weird network issues.

In my package.json I have these scripts at the moment:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ./src/server",
  "test": "gulp test",
  "deploy": "npm prune && npm install && gulp",
  "deploy-dev": "npm run-script deploy && pm2 startOrRestart ./etc/pm2/development.json"
}
```

I run `deploy-dev` which runs the `deploy` script. I want two improvements:

- How can I get notified by email when the above `npm install` has failed? Is there a command for that?
- Can I somehow automatically repeat `npm install` one minute only after it has failed?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: why? why not just check if it failed via logs, you could then fix the issue, and Einstein said: `Insanity: doing the same thing over and over again and expecting different results` What makes you think anything will change a minute later? I suggest you fix your networking issues...

Comment: good questions. first, i do not want to manually log into the server and check the log files each time i deploy. i am talking about automated deployment here. secondly, npm sometimes has vagrant issues on their backend. there is always a small risk of a network issue you shouldn't ignore when wanting to make the whole thing robust.

Comment: sometimes i also experience weird npm issues like these and want to be informed by email:
`80389 silly gentlyRm quitting because other entries in /var/www/videomail/development/node_modules
80390 error EEXIST, open '/home/nodejs/.npm/9765d813-adable-stream-1-0-31-package-tgz.lock'
File exists: /home/nodejs/.npm/9765d813-adable-stream-1-0-31-package-tgz.lock
Move it away, and try again.`

Comment: Michael, have you thought about installing all packages before sending the project to the server, that way `npm install` wont fail.

Comment: I know what you mean but that's bad practice. node_modules belong to .gitignore for many good reasons.